# DS won't power up

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-ds

My son's DS won't power up when the button is pushed. It worked fine up until now, but it is about 5 years old. We have tried charging it (with several chargers in case that is the issue) and there is no lights/no response. Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since a power failure can be caused for many reasons, it tough to say for sure.  There are two fuses in these guys, and it's possible that one of them has been blown.  There are instructions to remove and short-cut the fuse with a piece of wire [here](http://www.dcemu.co.uk/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=94191).  Alternatively, you can purchase replacement fuses online.

If it's the system's power supply or other failed component, you're better off buying a new one.  While these aren't very repairable, their low-cost makes them relatively replaceable.

Answer (score 2):

It could just be a broken battery. Do you know anyone with a working DS? If so, remove their good battery and try it out in yours (they're simple to swap, you just need a small screwdriver). New replacement DS batteries are cheap to buy. Good luck :)